# Pandas: how to map one dataframe onto another with missing data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, datetime

I'm sure an easy command exists to do this in pandas, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

I have two dataframes, the first is an **ideal **stock market timeline (times where I expect data to exist). The second dataframe is the **actual **data, with gaps. I need to map one to the other, and **fill in the gaps with NaN.**

First DataFrame: (an ideal timeline)

```
              datetime
0     2005-01-03 10:00:00
1     2005-01-03 11:00:00
2     2005-01-03 12:00:00
3     2005-01-03 13:00:00
4     2005-01-03 14:00:00
```

Second DataFrame: (actual data with missing value at time 12:00:00)

```
              datetime     open     high      low    close   volume
1  2005-01-03 10:00:00  15.1118  15.1745  14.7478  14.8294   586463
2  2005-01-03 11:00:00  14.8294  14.9737  14.7792  14.9423   344888
3  2005-01-03 13:00:00  15.0490  15.0929  14.9549  14.9612   343767
4  2005-01-03 14:00:00  14.9674  15.0616  14.9674  15.0051   364739
```

I want the finished product to be:

```
              datetime     open     high      low    close   volume
1  2005-01-03 10:00:00  15.1118  15.1745  14.7478  14.8294   586463
2  2005-01-03 11:00:00  14.8294  14.9737  14.7792  14.9423   344888
3  2005-01-03 12:00:00  Nan      NaN      NaN      NaN       NaN
4  2005-01-03 13:00:00  15.0490  15.0929  14.9549  14.9612   343767
5  2005-01-03 14:00:00  14.9674  15.0616  14.9674  15.0051   364739
```

where the dataframe's datetime column is now the *ideal* timeseries, and missing points are NaN

I've tried to study the documentation on this but I'm still a noob and I can't figure this out. Any suggestions?

Comment: left-[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) should work: `df1.merge(df2, how='left')`

Comment: if needed, specify the column explicitly (but that shouldn't be needed here): `df1.merge(df2, on='datetime', how='outer')`

Comment: `merge` is overkill for this problem and many times slower than needed. Use `reindex()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) function on pandas. Merge the two dataframes on `datatime` and use `outer` on how parameter. Outer uses union of keys from both dataframes.

### sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
# First DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ['2005-01-03 10:00:00', '2005-01-03 11:00:00', '2005-01-03 12:00:00', '2005-01-03 13:00:00']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ['2005-01-03 10:00:00', '2005-01-03 11:00:00', '2005-01-03 13:00:00', '2005-01-03 14:00:00'],
                    'open': [15.1118, 14.8294,15.0490,14.9674],
                    'high': [15.1745, 14.9737,15.0929,15.0616],
                    'low': [14.7478,14.7792,14.9549,14.9674],
                    'close': [14.8294,14.9423,14.9612,15.0051],
                    'volume': [586463,344888,343767,364739]})
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2,how='outer' ,on = 'datetime')
merged_df
```

### output:

[image]

### Reference:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, it is quite simple. You can prepare the desired index (`ix` below), then `df.reindex(ix)` is the result you are looking for (assuming your `df` has `'datetime'` as index --if not, make it so with `df = df.set_index('datetime')`). If the index is that of another DataFrame, then use that instead of making `ix` from scratch. If you just want to make sure the index is at hourly frequency and complete, then no need for `ix`: just `df.resample('H').asfreq()` is the value you want.

**Note: here, there is no need to use `pd.merge()`. It is overkill for this problem and many times slower in this case.**

Example (using your `df`):

```py
start, end = '2005-01-03 10:00:00', '2005-01-03 14:00:00'
ix = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='H')
>>> df.reindex(ix)
                        open     high      low    close    volume
2005-01-03 10:00:00  15.1118  15.1745  14.7478  14.8294  586463.0
2005-01-03 11:00:00  14.8294  14.9737  14.7792  14.9423  344888.0
2005-01-03 12:00:00      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN       NaN
2005-01-03 13:00:00  15.0490  15.0929  14.9549  14.9612  343767.0
2005-01-03 14:00:00  14.9674  15.0616  14.9674  15.0051  364739.0
```

With this specific `ix`, you get the same with simply:

```py
>>> df.resample('H').asfreq()
# same as above
```

Note: the initial `df` is the one you use as example, with `'datetime'` set as index:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'datetime': pd.to_datetime([
        '2005-01-03 10:00:00', '2005-01-03 11:00:00', '2005-01-03 13:00:00', '2005-01-03 14:00:00']),
    'open': [15.1118, 14.8294, 15.049, 14.9674],
    'high': [15.1745, 14.9737, 15.0929, 15.0616],
    'low': [14.7478, 14.7792, 14.9549, 14.9674],
    'close': [14.8294, 14.9423, 14.9612, 15.0051],
    'volume': [586463, 344888, 343767, 364739],
}).set_index('datetime')

>>> df
                        open     high      low    close  volume
datetime                                                       
2005-01-03 10:00:00  15.1118  15.1745  14.7478  14.8294  586463
2005-01-03 11:00:00  14.8294  14.9737  14.7792  14.9423  344888
2005-01-03 13:00:00  15.0490  15.0929  14.9549  14.9612  343767
2005-01-03 14:00:00  14.9674  15.0616  14.9674  15.0051  364739
```

#### Speed

Let's see what happens at scale, and compare solutions:

```py
start, end = '2005', '2010'
ix = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='H', inclusive='left')
cols = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']

np.random.seed(0)  # reproducible example
fulldf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(size=(len(ix), len(cols))), index=ix, columns=cols)

df = fulldf.sample(frac=.9).sort_index().copy(deep=True)
>>> df.shape
(39442, 5)
```

Now:

```py
t0 = %timeit -o df.reindex(ix)
# 1.57 ms ± 42.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

By contrast:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ix})
df2 = df.rename_axis(index='datetime').reset_index()

t1 = %timeit -o pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on = 'datetime')
# 14.3 ms ± 129 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

>>> t1.best / t0.best
9.312707763833396
```

Conclusion: `reindex()` is 9x faster than `merge()` in this example.